# frame work for mobile website supporting most mobile broswers like Opera mini

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

Im really confused on which frame work to be used for my mobile website.I have a website which is built on bootstrap,but found that many mobile broswers like opera and safari and not rendering the site well and many components are not even working well.

Now I m going to build a mobile site,exclusively for mobiles.I dont know which is the best css framework for mobile.
I have found that many of the componensts I used where running really bad on opera mini.i have tried jquery mobile.it has got a bunch of scripts which making my sites load very slow.

Can someone suggest a good framework which runs flawlessly on mobiles and has pretty decent UI components?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you another very very simple and minimalistic Grid system: [PocketGrid](http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/). Only 1 KB minified. Loot at demos and description. ;-)